# One-To-One between Fos-user-bundle and custom entity - no mapping found

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I wanted to create a database relationship between fosuserbundle and my Leed entity. I created the entire relationship by make: entity and easily created relationships in the database. I can download both the user entity, the leed and the user entity leed.

The problem is currently in two cases. Both when I want to download all leeds simply or if I want to download leeds by the user.

SIMPLE GET ALL LEDS:

```
$leed = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Leed::class)
    ->find(1);
```

GET ERROR:

```
No mapping found for field 'leed' on class 'App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User'.
```

TRY TO GET THROUGH USER:

```
 $leed = $user->getLeed();
```

GOT ERROR:

```
Return value of App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User::getLeed() must be an instance of App\Entity\Leed, null returned
```

MY LEED ENTITY:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LeedRepository")
 */
class Leed
{

...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="leed", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $user;

    public function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
```

MY USER ENTITY:

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

//use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
//use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use App\Entity\Leed;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the SonataEasyExtendsBundle.
 *
 * @link https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends
 *
 * References:
 * @link http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="company", message="Firma o tej nazwie już została zarejestrowana w systemie.")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setRoles([]);
//        $this->username = 'empty';
//        $this->company = 'empty';
//        $this->city = 'empty';
//        $this->nip = 'empty';
//        $this->postcode = 'empty';
        // your code here
    }


...
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Leed", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $leed;

    public function getLeed(): Leed
    {
        return $this->leed;
    }

    public function setLeed(Leed $leed): self
    {
        $this->leed = $leed;

        return $this;
    }
```

HERE THE MAPPING INFO OUTPUT:

```
 Found 20 mapped entities:

 [OK]   App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 [OK]   App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
 [OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
 [OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGallery
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGalleryHasMedia
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia
 [OK]   App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 [OK]   App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
 [OK]   App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
 [OK]   App\Entity\Menu
 [OK]   App\Entity\TileLink
 [OK]   App\Entity\Order
 [OK]   App\Entity\Subpage
 [OK]   App\Entity\MenuItem
 [OK]   App\Entity\Leed
 [OK]   App\Entity\NewsletterEmail
 [OK]   App\Entity\Test
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
```

Can anyone help me solve this or understand errors?

---

Ok i made User entity like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Leed", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leed_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $leed;

public function getLeed(): ?Leed
{
    return $this->leed;
}

public function setLeed(?Leed $leed): self
{
    $this->leed = $leed;

    return $this;
}
```

There is no error if i try:

```
$leed=$user->getLeed();
```

but that gives me a NULL

---

another situation is if i try to do:

```
    $leed = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Leed::class)
        ->find(1);
```

i got error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: leed
```

i made enitis like:

user:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Leed", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $leed;

    public function getLeed(): ?Leed
    {
        return $this->leed;
    }

    public function setLeed(?Leed $leed): self
    {
        $this->leed = $leed;

        return $this;
    }
```

and leed like:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leed")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;
```

---

user entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Leed", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leed_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $leed;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLeed()
{
    return $this->leed;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $leed
 */
public function setLeed($leed): void
{
    $this->leed = $leed;
}
```

and leed entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leed")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;
```

Comment: you have a one-to-one association that *requires* a Leed to exist for every User, and I would assume that's not the case. Have you checked your user table in database has a field `leed_id`?

Comment: in leed is user and in fos_user_user table is leed both are with key connected. All of leed column in user table are null. I put only for one user id of leed.

Comment: the name of field in table for example leed is user not user_id, it is neccesery to named it user_id ?

Comment: well, the *default* for a foreign key in doctrine is to append `_id` to the entity name, if you want the column to be named differently, you need to add `@ORM\JoinColumn` annotations: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn ... Also, since your columns are null, you should set the joincolumn nullable! also, your methods (User::get/setLeed and Leed::get/setUser) should reflect that they may be given null / return null. (which is also the reason for your second error, it returned null, but claims to return Leed)

Comment: ok i chaged in database manually the name to user_id and leed_id, how to setup in setters and getters and set entity too nullable true ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration and nullable for doctrine, you need the JoinColumn with nullable=true, yes.

Comment: join column in user entity yes?

Comment: like that: /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Leed", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Leed", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=true)
     */

Comment: Please check edited question at the bottom.

Comment: `name` in JoinColumn gets the name of the column in the database (which is most likely not "Leed" but "leed" or "leed_id", referencedColumnName can be omitted (and also is not user_id). if the Leed entity also has a user(_id) column, then you should add the @JoinColumn there with name="user(_id)", nullable=true, the rest should work automatically.

Comment: i set all up but this return me still null, no errors but null :/

Comment: i edited my question, look the setup

Comment: I took a look at my code to ensure my thought. The "User Entity" should use 'mappedBy="user" ' , and the "Leed Entity" should use 'inversedBy="leed" '

Comment: it is like that, look last edit question.

Comment: well, no errors is good for starters. now: do you have a User with a Leed (or other way around) to check if it works? (check in db!), if you do: how do you test that it's `null`?

Comment: I am try to get data like $leed = $user->getLead(); and its null, in DB by phpmyadmin works fine, i can click from table user to leed and from leed to user so FKEY works fine.

Comment: intrested is that if i`ll try to get data like $leed=$this->getDoctrinne()->getRepository(Leed::class)->findAll() thats give me error like: Notice: Undefined index: leed This all information are in question descriped

Comment: adn schema:validate show me error like that:  [FAIL] The entity-class App\Entity\Leed mapping is invalid:
 * The association App\Entity\Leed#user refers to the inverse side field App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#leed which does not exist.

Comment: and in User is a private $leed;

Comment: anyone got some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

So now i have configuration like that:

Entity User:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Leed", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leed_id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $leed;
```

Entity Leed:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leed")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

If i try to do:

```
$leed = $user->getLead();
```

I am getting NULL result,
If i do:

```
    $leed = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Leed::class)
        ->find(1);
```

i got error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: leed
```

This is seriously insane...

Comment: anyone got some idea ?