# Symfony doctrine one-to-one not working, canot get leed for user

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I dunno why this entity not working. I know that is FosUserBundle The Entity User and i try to connect Leeds to every user.
So now i have configuration like that:

Entity User:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Leed", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leed_id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $leed;
```

Entity Leed:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leed")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

If i try to do:

```
$leed = $user->getLead();
```

I am getting NULL result, If i do:

```
$leed = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Leed::class)
    ->find(1);
```

i got error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: leed
```

---

I change Leed entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="Leeder", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $user;
```

and user entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Leed", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $leed;
```

i changed the column name from leed_id in user table to leed and there is no error, but problem is that still if i get user object dump there is still null same as $leed=$user->getLeed();

so now is like that:
User Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Leed")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leed", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $leed;
    
    /**
     * @return Leed|null
     */
    public function getLeed(): ?Leed
    {
        return $this->leed;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param Leed $leed
     */
    public function setLeed($leed): void
    {
        $this->leed = $leed;
    }
```

Leed Entity:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="leed")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
    public function setUser($user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

user.orm.xml

```
<one-to-one field="leed" target-entity="App\Entity\Leed" inversed-by="user">
    <cascade><cascade-remove /></cascade>
    <join-column name="leed" referenced-column-name="ID" on-delete="CASCADE" on-update="CASCADE"/>
</one-to-one>
```

Comment: here is full information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672274/one-to-one-between-fos-user-bundle-and-custom-entity-no-mapping-found

Comment: Your OneToOne mapping is not correctly defined. That is, you should define the join column only on one side of the connection [one-to-one](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional). The second error sounds to be related to some other error in your entity definition - you could include the id field definition of that entity)